# How to apply Risch Algorithm by hand to solve integrals?

Tags: integration, symbolic-computation

In a German forum, a user asked how the "Feynman"-trick works. The example was
$$
f(x)=x e^{x}
$$
Another user mentioned that the Risch algorithm should be taught. Therefore, I wonder whether the Risch algorithm is useful for calculating antiderivates by hand. My questions:

1. Would the Risch algorithm be useful to find antiderivatives of, for example, $x e^{x}$ by hand? If so, how?
2. How can Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica solves (almost) every integral you give to them? What's the method they use?

Comment: 1. No. The antiderivative of $xe^x$ is fairly easy to guess given practice or just trial and error. Risch’s algorithm is (afaik) a hundred pages long in description and a general pain to implement – I would be highly surprised if it didn’t involve concepts too complex to explain to someone who can’t compute that kind of antiderivative.

Comment: You can find a description of how Mathematica computes integrals here: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5832/DefiniteIntegration.pdf . The Risch "algorithm" is a bit of a misnomer: the final step, checking algebraic equivalence between the derivatives of candidate answers and the original problem is undecidable, and in fact, symbolic integration is equivalent to the halting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Risch algorithm is rather complicated. Wikipedia page has few cute example, but you will see they degenerate fast. The function you wrote down is easily integrable even without Feynman's trick (a by parts integration is faster, to me). If you want a good example via Feynman's trick, use this

$$\int \ln(2 + \text{tg}^2(x))\ \text{d}x$$

W. Mathematica makes use of billions of lines of codes, which space from numerical computations, to symbolic calculations, to approximations, asymptotic, infinite series, infinite products and so on.

It can return the solution of some integral in terms of special functions, which are generally defined by infinite series, or by other integrals (which can be represented as infinite series too, ish) or numerical evaluations (with high precision, but still not analytical).

In any case, I have seen over here people who could solve analytically exactly o numerically exactly integrals by hand and mind that W. Mathematical couldn't, so it's all a matter of fun, time, energy and skills.